# connect to Django DB SQLite from different computers

Tags: django, database, sqlite

I have a Database on django in sqlite3 i want to get access to those tables from different computers with python script to get data update data ect...

How do i connect in python to those table?

Tnx for the help

Comment: Isn't that what the Django app is for?

Comment: I use it as a table and want different people to look or update or get data

Comment: I just cant find how to connect to this database

Comment: You don't, you write an API in Django using something like django-rest-framework and connect to that.

Comment: Can you explain?